# How to resolve this mistake in Petersons algorithm for process synchronization

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, operating-system, synchronization

### Information

I was reading the book of E. Tanenbaum about Modern operating systems and there was a code snippet that was introducing **Petersons algorithm for process synchronization** which is implemented with software.

Here's the snippet.

````
```
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1
#define N 2 /* number of processes */
int turn; /* whose turn is it? */
int interested[N]; /* all values initially 0 (FALSE) */
void enter_region(int process) /* process is 0 or 1 */
{
    int other; /* number of the other process */
    other = 1 − process; /* the opposite of process */
    interested[process] = TRUE; /* show that you are interested */
    turn = process; /*set flag*/
    while (turn == process && interested[other] == TRUE); /* null statement */
}
void leave_region(int process) { /* process: who is leaving */
    interested[process] = FALSE; /* indicate departure from critical region */
}
```
````

### The question is

**Isn't there a mistake?** [Edit] Must'nt it be `turn = other` or maybe there is another mistake.
This version of algorithm violates rules of mutual exclusion.

[Edit]
I think this version is violating the rules of mutual exclusion. As if first process sets the `interested` variable than stops and other process runs, second process can idle wait after setting his `interested` and `turn` variables without any need as there is no any process in critical section.

### Any answer and help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think there’s an error in the algorithm? Do you understand the purpose of setting and monitoring `turn`?

Comment: @Sneftel I think this version is violating the rules of mutual exclusion. If first process sets the `interested` variable than stops and other process runs, second process can idle wait without any need after setting his `interested` and `turn` variables, as there is not any process in critical section.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include a sequence of operations you think could lead to things going wrong.

Comment: You should also probably clarify  what you mean by “it is humbling algorithm”. That’s not a meaningful phrase.

Comment: @Sneftel Thanks for advice! I've edited the question. I saw in YouTube video that it is humbling algorithm and I don't understand it very clearly, so I deleted that phrase.

Comment: I wonder why this is tagged as c++

Answer (score 0):

If process 0 sets `interested[0]`, and then process 1 runs `enter_region` up until the loop, then process 0 will be able to exit the loop because `turn == process` is no longer true for it. `turn`, in this case, really means "turn to wait", and protects against exactly the situation you described. In contrast,  if the code did `turn = other` then process 0 would not be able to exit the loop *until* process 1 started waiting.